# I want to get some values of a table with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i need to get with selenium, in python, the values of the first and second colum of this table and i don't know how do that -.-

[This is a part of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzYI8.png)

This is my code:

```py
import random
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://es.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=1035793')

boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
boton.click()

sleep(random.uniform(5.0, 10.0))

lista = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="data_interval"]/option[3]')
lista.click()

sleep(random.uniform(10.0, 20.0))

registro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PromoteSignUpPopUp"]/div[2]/i')
registro.click()

sleep(random.uniform(8.0, 10.0))

tablas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="curr_table"]')

for tabla in tablas:
    fecha = tabla.find_element_by_class('first left bold noWrap').text
    precio = tabla.find_element_by_class('')
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code you've written so far ? This will help getting your question answered quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the list of element in for loop and get your desired column  or whatever you want .

1.In inspect check column 1 and 2 index
2.get the list list of all columns
3.put a check inside your for loop where the index is 1 column and 2 column
4.Then with the help of getText get the values .